# children nodes in treeview in php

Tags: php, treeview, nodes, children

i have tried to make a treeview but i can't create the children nodes with information.

In get_data file i have the above code:

```
$result = array();
$rs = mysql_query("select * from dados where id=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $node = array();
    $node['id'] = $row['id'];
    $node['text'] = $row['nome_cliente'];
    $node['state'] = 'closed';

    $node['children'] = has_child(2);
    array_push($result,$node);
}

echo json_encode($result);

function has_child($id2){

    $result2 = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("select id from dados where id=$id2");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    return $row[0];
}
```

and in the view he returns me the parent nodes correctly but the children nodes appears "undefined".If anyone can help me i will appreciate.

Best regards.

Comment: I tested the code and found no error. I created a database like, and put the code to run. `[{"id":"1","text":"ds","state":"closed","children":"2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

No Error found.

https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/7435067

make sure the record actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

My output data is like that:

[{"id":"1","text":"joao","state":"closed","children":"2"},{"id":"1","text":"filipe","state":"closed","children":"2"}]

i think it seems fine but in the three at children nodes it appears "undefined" with no data instead of the data "2" that was suposed to be. It suposed to run ok but doesn't. If you can say me a ideia that what is wrong i will appreciate. Thank you for the answer before!

Best regards.